# How do I solve for $x$, when given three matrices multiplied together, equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How do I solve for $x$, when given a $1 \times 3$, $3 \times 3$, and $3 \times 1$ matrix, all multiplied together set equal to zero with an $x$ variable in two of the matrices?

The question asks to determine values of $x$ such that:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   x &&  2 &&  1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
   2 &&  0 && -2 \\
   0 &&  0 &&  0 \\
  -2 && -4 && -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
   x \\
  -1 \\
   4
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

Lets call the matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ respectively as they are ordered. I started by multiplying matrix $A$ and $B$, and resulted in a $1 \times 3$ matrix $AB$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  2x - 2 && -4 && -2x + 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then multiplied our new matrix with matrix $C$. The resultant $1 \times 1$ matrix was:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  2x^2 - 10x + 8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then factored out a $2$ to get:

$$
2 \begin{bmatrix}
  x^2 - 5x + 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then solved for values of $x$ that made it $0$, since the three matrices multiplied were initially set to equal $0$:

$$
2 \begin{bmatrix}
  (x - 1)(x - 4)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So it seems the problem is looking for the values $x = 1$ and $x = 4$, but upon submission it told me, the answers were wrong, so I feel I messed up somewhere or I’m missing other values. But I’ve gone through the problem a couple times and reached the same result. Can anyone point out my error or show me what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the correct method, but note that the AB should be

$$[2x-2,-4,-2x-1]$$

and thus

$$ABC=(2x-2)x-1(-4)+4(-2x-1)=0 \implies 2x^2-10x=0$$

Comment: Thank you! I made the same mistake of having 2x+1 instead of 2x-1 all 3 times I did the problem. I found x=0 and x=5 to be the solutions and those were accepted as correct.

Comment: @DrewPesall Well done! You are welcome, Bye.